# How to get Facebook to see YouTube/Blip embeds when sharing a link?

Tags: links, facebook, embed

I run a sketch comedy channel that posts new content regularly. On our site (powered by WordPress.org) we embed Blip.tv players. The problem is, whenever we share a link on Facebook to one of our video pages on our site, it doesn't recognize that there's a video on the page at all. It just loads the featured image of the post. I'd like viewers to be able to watch our videos from their walls - anyone got an answer?

In case you're not sure what I'm talking about, here's a link to one of our video pages so you can test on FB for yourself: http://www.juliansmith.tv/2009/11/malk/

Answer (score 1):

<strike>All in One SEO plugin</strike> is setting your [FaceBook open graph meta tags](http://ogp.me/). For Facebook to "see" your video, you need to set video meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/movie.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/movie.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />
```

Whether or not this is possible with that plugin or will have to be done manually, I can't tell you.

**EDIT-** on second glance I missed the closing comment for the plugin, it appears the tags are being inserted by something else.

Comment: The problem with your method is that with WordPress, the <head> is located in the header.php file, which is loaded at the top of every page on the site. So your method basically only allows me to define one video URL for the entire site. We post new content regularly, so this isn't an option.

Comment: Is there some kind of PHP script I can use that will grab the url of the video in each specific post?